# Is it true that the USA funds a Shrimp Museum with the federal budget?

Tags: united-states, budget

Apparently, the USA funds a Shrimp Museum at the federal level; I'd imagine as a form of pork-barrel spending. However, I've been looking for this online but ain't found much, thus I ask this.

Is this true?
And if it is, exactly how much did they allocate? And where is this Museum?

Comment: What is the source for this claim?

Comment: My friends told me and it was mentioned on things like Secular Talk when he talks about the budget. I looked and didn't find much, thus I ask.

Comment: This belongs on skeptics.se if anywhere

Comment: @ColinZwanziger: "My friends told me" isn't notable enough for Skeptics.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define "shrimp museum."

The National Science Foundation (NSF) [has provided grants](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1010938) to zoos and aquariums like The Chicago Shedd Aquarium, usually for specific research purposes.

I could imagine how someone skeptical of federal government spending might hyperbolically refer to this as "federal spending on a shrimp museum," but ultimately it's part of a broad, complex system of federal grants provided by the NSF to advance scientific research for public benefit.

Comment: What specific public benefit that exceeds the grant cost in objective way is provided by a grant to study shrimp **in aquarium**? :)

Comment: @user4012 Would you rather study shrimp that have been thrown on the barbie?